# Why asp.net dropdownlist selectedvalue is not set during postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have issues getting the selected value of the dropdownlist during postback, the selectedlvalue is just not set.

However I can see that the values are posted to the server and can find the in Response.Form.

```
Request.Form["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ddlProvice"]  "4" string
```

It looks like the selected value is not binding to the dropdownlist server control.

I dont what to read the dropdowns selected value directly from the Response.Form. How can this be resolved?

Comment: Is the data added dynamically? Do you have `EnableViewState="false"` against the control?

Comment: yes, the values are populated dynamicaly, but how can the viewState effect this?

Comment: Please show the code where you are loading the data.

Comment: I'm using the cascadedropdownlist from ajaxcontroltoolkit. everything is straightforward there.. I already created a test project for this and it is working there. I'm having problem applying this solution to and existing project. I can see that the values are posted to the server, but they are not binded to the server control..

Comment: Generally if you can't access values on postback it means the control has been added to far along in the Page Life cycle. i.e After Page_Load. Are you binding this control as a result of another postback?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably binding the `DropDownList` in `postback` also that would be over writing the selected index. You can put binding of `DropDownList` in ! [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) block.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  //bind dropdownlist here
}
```